# Start Background task immediately after registering it in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1, microsoft-metro, windows-10

How can I run the background task immediately after registering it? It is found that background task runs in every 15 minutes interval but what is the exact time it takes to start background task after registering it?

Comment: From what I've tried, I wasn't able to start BT immediately. TimeTriggers seems to work with internal clock, which is quite logic. You don't know when will be the next tick - it can be in 5 or 10 minutes. So in this case for your first run you can wait up to little more that 20 minutes. After that next runs will go with constant interval. That's at least what I've tried. I'm also not sure if for Windows Phone minimum interval won't be 30 minutes instead of 15.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need to start BackgroundTask immediately (10 seconds) after registering it.